# Why Spring Data does not throw an error when saving an entity with an ID that does not exists in the database?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a test updating an entity, everything works fine if the record exists in the database, however, if the record does not exists, instead of trying an update, it does an insert, ignoring the ID field and updating it with the ID from the database.

Using MySQL.

A simple entity:

```
@Entity
public class DummyTable {

    public DummyTable() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String notes;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }
}
```

With JPA repo

```
public interface DummyTableRepository extends JpaRepository<DummyTable, Integer> {
}
```

And my test

```
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private DummyTableRepository dummyTableRepository;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        var dummyRegistry = new DummyTable();
        dummyRegistry.setId(100);
        dummyRegistry.setNotes("");

        var result = dummyTableRepository.save(dummyRegistry);

        Assertions.assertEquals(result.getId(), dummyRegistry.getId());
    }

}
```

My problem is, if the record does not exists, the entity gets added to the database with some ID

[image: Example of ID being replaced]

If the id does exists everything works fine

[image]

So, why is this the default behavior? according to the docs, if it finds and ID, it will try an update, I understand is not normal that the ID does not exists, but then why an error is not thrown?

Comment: This document might help you https://www.adoclib.com/blog/how-spring-data-jpa-checks-whether-to-perform-update-or-save.html

Answer (score 1):

@GeneratedValue will ignore provided Id if it doesn´t exists and it will insert a record using the autoincrement approach of the db. If you want to change the behavior of the Ids, you would need to create your own sequence generator.

https://ntsim.uk/posts/how-to-use-hibernate-identifier-sequence-generators-properly

More info about the GeneratedValue https://www.tutorialandexample.com/hibernate-generatedvalue-strategies

Comment: But why Spring tried an insert and not an update? according to the default behavior, if the Id field is not null, it will try the command as an update https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites.strategies

Comment: did you try the Example 56? I have seem in others stackoverflow questions that this approach works.